# Inner join on Django with where clause?

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm trying to filter out a ModelForm to only display dropdown values tied to a specific user.

I've got three tabled tied together:

`User`, `Project`, `ProjectUser`.

One user can have many projects, and one projects can have many users, and the table `ProjectUser` is just a joined table between `User` and `Project`, e.g

```
id | project_id | user_id 
1      5            1
2      6            2
3      6            1
```

How would I write the following inner join query in Django ORM?

```sql
SELECT name
FROM projectuser
INNER JOIN project 
ON projectuser.project_id = project.id
WHERE user_id = <request.user here>
```

Comment: Do you mean how to write it with Django's ORM? Can you share the code you wrote when you attempted a solution?

Comment: I tried something like
`self.fields['project'].queryset = ProjectUser.objects.filter(user_id__id=user.id).select_related('user', 'project')`
But that just returns something like "<QuerySet [<ProjectUser: ProjectUser object (1)>, <ProjectUser: ProjectUser object (3)>]>"

I need the name of the actual `Project`, which sits on the `Project` table

Comment: Maybe `ManyToManyField` is what you need.

Comment: The datamodel is fine - I just need a way to fetch the relationship through Django ORM. My raw sql query above solves my issue, I just need to translate that to Django ORM

Comment: `Project.objects.filter(project_user__user=user)` ?

Comment: That actually solves it, thanks a lot. Just had to change it to
`Project.objects.filter(projectuser__user=user)`

No idea the ORM could do that. The query doesn't make sense, but it works :O

Comment: Django ORM returns the model you used first. (If you start with Project, Project is returned.) You can see Raw SQL by using the following code. :) 

`print(str(Project.objects.filter(projectuser__user=user)).query)`

Comment: If you make a new answer I'll make it as solved. Thanks for your help. I'm just surprised by the amount of magic happening behind the scenes. Basically by just using `projectuser` in the filter, Django knows that it should look for a related table..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Django ORM applies a Filter to a field specified as a foreign key, Django ORM understands that it is a related table and joins it.

```py
Project.objects.filter(projectuser__user=user)
```

You can join multiple tables, or even apply a filter to the reverse of a foreign key! You can use the `related_name` of the ForeignKey field appropriately.

Comment: Good guess but it does not correspond with SQL in question

Answer (score 1):

#### You original SQL

> ```
> SELECT name
> FROM projectuser
> INNER JOIN project 
> ON projectuser.project_id = project.id
> WHERE user_id = <request.user here>
> ```

So as i see your SQL, you want to get list of `name` from `projectuser` for specific `user`. If so, here is the answer

```
ProjectUser.objects.filter(user_id = user).values_list('name', flat = True)
```

I see you accept answer with `Project.objects.filter(projectuser__user=user)`

For this answer your SQL should look like this

> ```
> SELECT name
> FROM project
> INNER JOIN projectuser 
> ON projectuser.project_id = project.id
> WHERE projectuser.user_id = <request.user here>
> ```